# How to use the response object from model.save() for the collection?

Tags: javascript, php, rest, backbone.js

this is what I have:

```
var List = define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {
return Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/lists',

    getId: function() {
        return this.get('id');
    },

    getTitle: function() {
        return this.get('title');
    }
});

var lists = define(['backbone', 'model/list'], function(Backbone, List) {
    return Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: '/lists',
        model: List
    });
});
```

In my view I create a new model with `var model = new List(); model.save({title: '<test>'})`. The post request to the server will create a new entry in the database, but before that I use hmtlspecialchars() to get rid of the injected HTML code. The response will return the parsed data. On the frontend side I want to store the parsed model instead of the model which created on the frontend. How to solve that? I only found solution for saving the model directly in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fool! After creating the question I was able to solve my issue. Just use the success callback from the model:

```
var list = new List();
list.save(data, {
    success: function(model,response) {
        self.collection.add(response);
    }
});
```

When I tried this before I used the model from the callback what is the model which I have sent to the backend. I got it solved, but maybe there is a better solution?